# WPF Trigger / Style overrides another

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles, datatrigger

I have a `ListView` with an `ItemContainerStyle` defined as such:

```
                            <ListView Width="auto" 
                              SelectionMode="Single"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContStyle}"
                               ....
```

Then in `baseListViewStyle`, I have defined some base styles to apply to my `ListView`s, including a `Style` trigger:

```
<Style x:Key="baseListViewStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The `Trigger` here highlights the row when mouse is over it. Nice.

I also have a `DataTrigger` on the `ListViewItem`:

```
                <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTestTrue}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SomeFunkyAnimation}" />
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
```

If test is true then a nice little fade animation is played out. This all works except when I move my mouse over the row where "test is true" the animation stops and the mouse over style is displayed.

Any ideas how I can override that style in my `DataTrigger`?

TIA

**Update:**

`SomeFunkyAnimation` animates the background colour. The xaml for it is here:

```
            <Style x:Key="ItemContStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseListViewStyle}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="SomeFunkyAnimation" FillBehavior="Stop">
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" RepeatBehavior="Forever"  From="Red" To="Pink" Duration="0:0:3"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>
```

The `MouseOver` trigger is defined in `baseListViewStyle`. The `DataTrigger` is defined in `ItemContStyle`.

I tried removing the `MouseOver` style trigger but that didn't work as I believe the `Listview` has a default `MouseOver` style already defined so it overrides my `DataTrigger` animation.

Comment: What does your *funky animation* animate? The `Foreground` property as well? And where is your `DataTrigger` defined? In the default `ListViewItem` style, or is it a local style? More important: Are the `IsMouseOver` trigger and the `DataTrigger` defined in the *same* style?

Comment: gehho...thanks for looking. Answers in original question.

Comment: Hmmm, I do not see the error then. Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after dropping a few hours of my life on this problem I finally found a work around. For some reason ColorAnimation just stops animating after a mouse over. Dont know why, maybe a wpf bug who knows. Solution was to rejig my animation. The below does the same thing:

```
                    <Storyboard x:Key="SomeFunkyAnimation" FillBehavior="Stop">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="true"  From="0.2" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
```

And then same DataTrigger with an additional Setter for the background:

```
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTestTrue}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SomeFunkyAnimation}" />
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
```

Peace at last.